# Recognition if an entry into a cell is a date or a year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A              B          C    
1    08-07-2017         Date
```

In **Cell A1** the user can I either enter a **Date** or a **Year**. In **Cell B1** it should automatically be recognised if the user entered a **Date** or a **Year**.
For this I use the following formula so far:

```
B1 = IF(A1<=2958465,"Date","Years")
```

This formula works perfectly for **Dates** so when I enter for example `08-07-2017` the result in **Cell B1** is `Date`. However, when I enter a **Year** for example `2017` the value in **Cell A1** is displayed as `09-07-1905` and in **Cell B1** the result remains **Date**. Probably both issues appear because **Cell A1** is formated as a `Date`.

Do you have any idea how I have to change the formula in **Cell B1** or the format in **Cell A1** to get the following result:

a) Show the word `Date` in **Cell B1** in case a date is entered into **Cell A1** 
b) Show the word `Years` in **Cell B1** in case a year is entered into **Cell A1** 
c) Change the format in **Cell A1** from `Date` to `Number` if a `Year` is entered instead of a `Date`.

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of the number `2958465` in your formula? You can determine whether a cell is Date/Time formatted using `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D","Date/Time formatted","not Date/Time formatted")`. But "Change the format in Cell A1 from Date to Number if a Year is entered instead of a Date." is not possible without using `VBA`.

Comment: possible solution if there is a defined acceptable date range and year range.